# How to implement select function call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have created a virtual node "/dev/abc" and there are 2 applications a.c and b.c

a.c will write data in to the node,
b.c will read data from the node

In b.c I am opening the node and using select function
to verify whether data is available in the node.

I am using below code for checking the data.
But with out writing data from a.c, b.c is reading the
data.

Code:

```
fd_set read set;
int result;
fd=open ("/dev/abc", O_RDWR);
FD_SET (fd, &readset);
result=select (fd+1,&readset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(result> 0)
{
    if (FD_ISSET (fd, &readset))
    {
       read (fd, buffer, 100);
     }
}
```

Please suggest me how to use select function call for 
the above scenario.

Regards, 
Ajith Kumsi

Comment: Why are you trying to use `select` and not `poll`?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `FD_ZERO()` before `FD_SET()` to clear your `readset`. That's probably the reason. There is a clear example near the bottom of [select man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) and you can just follow it.

Comment: An issue I have with the select man page and a lot of tutorials on-line that use select is that they do not explicitly explain why one should call FD_ZERO before FD_SET. They just do it and assume you either know or follow their example exactly.  (One has to FD_ZERO before FD_SET because FD_SET would be working on uninitialized memory otherwise.)